# ImplicitlyWait is not recognized winform

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But when I want to add it to my project, it doesn't work and reports an error

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV7NA.png)

I used the `*using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;` , but not working

So how to use it, please help me, everyone. Thanks very much

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImplicitlyWait()` is obsolete. Use `ImplicitWait` property

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use this when starting chrome? Try this:

```
 _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```